# Sci-fi Book About Two Planets Sharing the Same Atmosphere?

Tags: story-identification, books

In the early 2000s I read a good sci-fi fantasy book about two binary planets that shared the same atmosphere at one point. The inhabitants used hot air balloons/gondolas to travel from one planet to the other.

What was the book called?

I've been searching on google for hours with no luck. However I can say its not the *Flight of the Dragonfly/Rocheworld* book series. Additionally, I suspect this book was used as inspiration for *Lexx*, season 3 "Fire and Water."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would probably be one of the books in the *[Land and Overland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_and_Overland)* series by Bob Shaw:  *The Ragged Astronauts* (1986), *The Wooden Spaceships* (1988), and *The Fugitive Worlds* (1989).  The first book is probably the most likely.

From Wikipedia's description of *The Ragged Astronauts*:

> Land is a strictly feudal society that undergoes a peak energy crisis (the trees that provide energy and hard materials are scarce), and is undergoing a process of cultural decay. Much of the human population of Land travels to Overland via hot-air balloon to escape airborne creatures called the Ptertha.

[image: Cover Image]

(Previously asked about here:  [Book series with a double planet system and poisonous bubbles that float around](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/203105/book-series-with-a-double-planet-system-and-poisonous-bubbles-that-float-around) )